# Changing size of font in chart title

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that creates 2 lines of text in the chart title so the first line acts as the actual title, and the second line represents the subtitle.

**Is there a way to alter this code so the first line has a font size of 24 and the second line has a font size of 18?**

The lines refer to a cell that a user can enter their own title and subtitle into so I can't really go off of exact characters...Thank you!

```
With ActiveChart
            .ChartStyle = 2
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = Worksheets(4).Range("J13") & Chr(10) & Worksheets(4).Range("J14") 
End with
```

Cell J13 is the cell where the first line of text comes from, J14 contains the second line of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a good start, you might have to adjust a bit the variables `StartChar` and `LenSize` to fit accurately :

```
Sub Alex664()
Dim StartChar As Integer, _
    LenSize As Integer

With ActiveChart
    .ChartStyle = 2
    .HasTitle = True
    With .ChartTitle
        .Text = Worksheets(4).Range("J13") & Chr(10) & Worksheets(4).Range("J14")
        StartChar = InStr(1, .Text, Chr(10))
        If StartChar <> 0 Then
            LenSize = Len(.Text) - StartChar + 1
            .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=StartChar).Font.Size = 24
            .Characters(Start:=StartChar + 1, Length:=LenSize).Font.Size = 18
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```